# Can I use an Apple charge Cube (5W power) through a Ripcord 9V to USB to feed a Roland SP 404 (2.7 W draw) Safely?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, safety, damage

I am asking this as I want to be extra sure this setup does not damage my 404 Sampler as its an expensive item of mine and it's very dear to me so I want to be careful. Here is the scenario:

I have this device: https://www.roland.com/us/products/sp-404/ that normally runs off a 9V 300mA power supply connected to the wall or a surge protector. I am planning on making it portable through using these items:

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD810LL/A/apple-5w-usb-power-adapter
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00GC0UZZM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GC0UZZM)

This setup is to run the device through the wall or any outlet on the go, as the original power supply is fairly bulky. Additionally, I'd like to connect it to a fairly large power bank, specifically this one..

[https://www.amazon.com/EC-Technology-Portable-22400mAh-Capacity/dp/B00FDK2G2C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FDK2G2C)

Is there any safety things I should worry about in regards to the electronics? Too much draw or output? I just don't want to fry my unit.

Comment: Off topic here. But theoretically yes, if the ripcord provides 9V up to 1A and the sampler only draws 0.3A. But the original supply provides up to 2A. And there is the issue of possible switching noise. I assume that 5V to 9V step up is using a boost switching regulator. Switching noise may cause noise issues on your sampler. Or possible ground loop noise from a ac usb adapter.

Comment: An alternative to the ripcord is to use a usb C PD usb supply or power bank that can provide 9V, and a usb pd trigger module for 9V. Some assembly required.

Comment: I am not sure what a boost switching regulator is, I am also not familiar enough with electronics to do any sort of assembly. I don't even know how to solder. From what I understand in your comment, I am guessing there is a problem with the 5watt cube? If I have a 9v to Usb cable connected to the 5 watt cube, which is connected to a wall, and the sampler draws 2.7 watts (9v 300mA) then will it be okay or not? At first you said yes but then you confused me with the possible issues, none of which I have the technical familiarity to fully understand what it means.

Comment: Rough translation: try it and see if it works. It is unlikely to damage the 404, but there might be noise issues.

Comment: Where would the noise issues be coming from? Passer mentioned the 5V stepping up to 9V. I am guessing the cube is not providing enough voltage and something in it's internals is causing it to provide the 9V (boost switching regulator?) at the cost of noise in my system. Is this correct? In that case I might need a 9V cube to use instead